# Replace values in a java collection

Tags: java, collections

I want to change the values of a collection of unknown type. I found `java.util.Collections.replaceAll`, but that works only for Lists. I helped myself creating a new new Collection and adding the changed elements.

```
if (o instanceof Collection) {
            Collection<Object> newCollection = (Collection<Object>) o.getClass().newInstance();
            for (Iterator<Object> it = ((Collection<Object>)o).iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                newCollection.add(doSomethingWith(it.next()));
            }

            return newCollection;
}
```

But I liked to return the same List as result. Any ideas?

Comment: How about this: `Collections.replaceAll(new ArrayList(yourCollection), old, new);`.  If you want to return it, just save the new list to a variable before doing the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this without requiring the collection to be of a specific type: since collections are not required to be ordered, the only method that lets you add items to a `Collection` is `add`, which inserts at an unspecified place in the collection.

Collection iterators do not let you modify collection elements either: some iterators let you remove the current item, but there is no "replace" method on collection iterators.

[`ListIterator<T>` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) provides a `set(T)` method, but it locks you into using a `List<T>`, for which you already have a solution.

Note that your method is not bulletproof either - it relies on the assumption that a collection passed into it has an accessible parameterless constructor.